# Help with EEPROM log: RPI4 does not boot

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, pi4-eeprom, eeprom

This is another "RPI does not boot". I have tried many thins now and I'm not able to figure out why my RPI4 (that is quite valuable these days) does not boot. EEPROM is working fine and I followed [this post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=320462#p1919044) to output the early boot log to UART. This is what I get:

```
RPi: BOOTLOADER release VERSION:507b2360 DATE: 2022/04/26 TIME: 11:24:28 BOOTMODE: 0x00000006 part: 0 BUILD_TIMESTAMP=1650968668 0x470108a2 0x00b03111 0x0006668c
PM_RSTS: 0x00001000
part 00000000 reset_info 00000000
uSD voltage 3.3V
Initialising SDRAM 'Micron' 16Gb x1 total-size: 16 Gbit 3200
DDR 3200 0 0 16 152

XHCI-STOP
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
USBSTS 11
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
xHC ports 5 slots 32 intrs 4
Reset USB port-power 1000 ms
xhci_set_port_power 1 0
xhci_set_port_power 2 0
xhci_set_port_power 3 0
xhci_set_port_power 4 0
xhci_set_port_power 5 0
xhci_set_port_power 1 1
xhci_set_port_power 2 1
xhci_set_port_power 3 1
xhci_set_port_power 4 1
xhci_set_port_power 5 1
XHCI-STOP
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
USBSTS 18
XHCI-STOP
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
USBSTS 19
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
xHC ports 5 slots 32 intrs 4
Boot mode: SD (01) order f54
USB2[1] 400202e1 connected
USB2 root HUB port 1 init
DEV [01:00] 2.16 000000:01 class 9 VID 2109 PID 3431
HUB init [01:00] 2.16 000000:01
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000000 BUS: 200000 Hz actual: 200000 HZ div: 1250 (625) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 540
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000f00 BUS: 200000 Hz actual: 200000 HZ div: 1250 (625) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 540
OCR c0ff8000 [2]
CID: 002750485344333247606c6ac0cc0143
CSD: 400e00325b590000e7177f800a400000
SD: bus-width: 4 spec: 2 SCR: 0x02058083 0x01000000
SD HOST: 250000000 CTL0: 0x00000f04 BUS: 50000000 Hz actual: 41666666 HZ div: 6 (3) status: 0x1fff0000 delay: 2
MBR: 0x00002000,  524288 type: 0x0c
MBR: 0x00082000, 7913472 type: 0x83
MBR: 0x00000000,       0 type: 0x00
MBR: 0x00000000,       0 type: 0x00
Trying partition: 0
type: 32 lba: 8192 oem: 'mkfs.fat' volume: ' boot       '
rsc 32 fat-sectors 4033 c-count 516190 c-size 1
root dir cluster 2 sectors 0 entries 0
FAT32 clusters 516190
Trying partition: 0
type: 32 lba: 8192 oem: 'mkfs.fat' volume: ' boot       '
rsc 32 fat-sectors 4033 c-count 516190 c-size 1
root dir cluster 2 sectors 0 entries 0
FAT32 clusters 516190
Read config.txt bytes     2075 hnd 0x51b
Read start4.elf bytes  2241824 hnd 0xf1f1
Read fixup4.dat bytes     5352 hnd 0x52f
Firmware: e5a963efa66a1974127860b42e913d2374139ff5 Mar 24 2022 13:19:26
0x00b03111 0x00000000 0x00000fff
MEM GPU: 76 ARM: 948 TOTAL: 1024
Starting start4.elf @ 0xfec00200 partition 0
XHCI-STOP
xHC ver: 256 HCS: 05000420 fc000031 00e70004 HCC: 002841eb
USBSTS 18
+
```

I don't really know how to read this, so any help is welcome. Another detail: I'm measuring the current consumption of the RPI connection and I get the expected 400-500mA when the boot sequence starts, but it drops to a constant ~300mA the moment the sequence stops (when the log stops as well).

Comment: As it says, it reads the fat partition... any difference when you remove all peripherals? Just giving power and sd?

Comment: No difference. The only peripheral I have is the HDMI cable. When removed, the output is the same.

Comment: Try uncommenting hdmi_safe=1 in config.txt and also making a file named ssh to enable it...beyond that lies fresh image, followed by new sd; i don't know why your pi does not boot